# socket io Websocket Disconnected Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I am actually facing an issue here. I am having a login page From there I am going to another page. From there I am getting my socket disconnected.

What i am trying to  do is

### In my server side app.js

```
app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
req.session.username = req.body.usr;
req.session.password = req.body.pass; 
req.session.password = 380; 
authenticatAPI.logIn(req, res);
});
```

From here then to authenticate js(server side)

```
getUserName = req.body.usr;
getPassword = req.body.pass;
req.session.username = getUserName;
req.session.password = getPassword;
res.send({url:"screen1.html",id:100,usr:getUserName});
```

### From here to client side

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
```

When i reach here Again it goes for app.js and goes inside the io.on("connection") function ,here I am getting an error when i debug using node inspect.

"Remote debugging stopped Websocket closed reattach new target"
What should i do here....?

Comment: Do you realize that whenever you change pages in the browser, the webSocket will get disconnected and it will be up to the new page to connect again?  Each page in your site that wants to have an open webSocket has to open the webSocket itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to bet that you have node inspect set to break on caught exceptions. Try unchecking "Pause On Caught Exceptions" near the right hand side of the debugger.

[image]

Otherwise, you are likely using a 3rd party library that is using socket.io that is throwing this error.